# Faster conditional row operation

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements

A reproducible example,

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(1,3,1,2,3,4), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = T)
jj <- c(3:1)
> mat1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    1
[2,]    2    3    4
```

I want to check first row of mat1 and if there is 1 I want to do something, otherwise nothing happens. For example, with that 1, I add jj[i] and sum all together as following:

```
sumj <- 0
for (i in 1:length(jj)){
if (mat1[1,i] == 1){
  sumj <- sumj + jj[i]
  }
}
```

In this case, I am checking all row elements one by one and registering the output. This works fine for this but I need to make it efficient as the original matrix has lot of rows and the calculation will be repeated many times. Can you suggest something?

PLEASE DO NOT FOCUS ON THE SUM AS IT CAN BE SOME OTHER COMPLEX FUNCTIONS.

Comment: Your code looks like it could be equivalent to `sum((mat1[1,]==1) * jj)`, since it processes just the first row of `mat1`. Not sure I got what you want. Maybe if you want to repeat the above for each row, `jj %*% t(mat1==1)` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of

```
colSums(t(mat1 == 1)*jj)
c((mat1 == 1) %*% jj)
```

will add the elements of `jj` corresponding to the matrix entries equal to 1, row by row. The matrix multiply based way is the fastest of the two.

---

Following the comment by the OP, here is a function that first checks whether there is a `value` in the matrix's first row and only computes a function `FUN` on the values of `vec` (`jj` in the question) if the corresponding element of the matrix row is equal to `value` (`1` in the question).

```
fun <- function(x, vec, FUN, value = 1){
  f <- match.fun(FUN)
  if(inherits(x, "array")){
    if(any(x[1, ] == value)){
      y <- f(t(x == value)*vec)
      t(y)
    } else NA
  } else NA
}

fun(mat1, jj, colSums)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    4    0
fun(mat1, jj, sin)
#        [,1] [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 0.14112    0 0.841471
#[2,] 0.00000    0 0.000000
```

Comment: I realized that, my question can drive people to provide solution focusing on sum. But my main intention is to use any function that would only execute if the first row has 1.

Comment: @Rel_Ai See if the function in the edit is what you are asking for.